# Computer boots to Grub command line

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I've three hard drives with Windows 8.1.1 installed on the first SSD and then Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on the third HDD.

In BIOS I've chosen to launch 
1. ubuntu 2. ubuntu 3. Windows Boot Manager 4. Windows Boot Manager (Why there are two entries for each one, I don't know).

But when I start the computer I get to a big black command window. If I there type exit it then launches past the MSI EFI screen and over to the "normal" GRUB screen with the ability to choose either Ubuntu or Windows 8. Why's there that it launches to the command line at first requiring me to type exit before actually launching the system?

Some extra info:

I've GRUB2.

Boot Repair tells me there was an error quoting 
"*An error occurred during the repair.
Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/8309104/
In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com 
You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdc (500GB) disk!*"

Hope that helps.

Also I do not have any option to boot from sdc rather than just that I want to boot Ubuntu or Windows as seen in my BIOS here: **https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qpg799h38az76gv/AABhGE1IKNq7SfXDlGesFNhNa?dl=0**

Thanks in advance!

*(PS. As you may notice I'm relatively new to Ubuntu, though I've had it as my primary OS before for a while on my laptop, but I'm not into all commands and such so take it easy on me DS.)*

**For complete info about the issues clarification please read through the comments on @oldfreds answer, there's a lot useful there**

Comment: The boot repair output looks generally ok. Which hard drive dos your (EFI) BIOS boot from? Grub is installed on sdc (500 GB).

Comment: Edited the post for you to see, thanks for helping me out hopefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was impossible as with UEFI you are supposed to use gpt. But you are using the efi partition on the sda gpt partitioned drive to boot an Ubuntu install on a MBR(msdos) drive.

Better to have sdc as gpt partitioned and include its own efi partition at beginning of drive so it could boot without sda. Some disconnect other drives, other partition in advance & use Something Else and make sure to install grub to correct drive. How you boot installer UEFI or BIOS is how it installs.

Did Boot-Repair convert your BIOS install to UEFI as I did not think installer would create your configuration.

I think some of the issue is the changing from BIOS to UEFI and vice versa. You do have BIOS based boot loaders in MBR.

You may have two entries for ubuntu, one is grub and the other is shim. Shim is for secure boot and grub is for UEFI non-secure boot.

Shows install with screen shots for both BIOS(purple) & UEFI(grub menu), so you know which you are using.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Also shows Windows 8 screens

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

["Install alongside" option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using "Something Else"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163962/install-alongside-option-missing-how-do-i-install-ubuntu-beside-windows-using)

Comment: Boot-Repair did not convert my install to UEFI but Ubuntu installed that way at first. Because during the install I got the UEFI grub meny and afterwards just to be sure it installed in UEFI mode I ran the command [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" and got the output EFI boot on HDD as expected. So should I reinstall Ubuntu in your opinion after formatting the sdc partition? Or are there anyother alternatives? (Since I would have to delete my Ubuntu configuration)

Comment: I could if it would help in anyway tape the boot process so you could see how it starts up.

Comment: I would just reinstall if a new install that you have not reconfigured and have info you want backed up first. I would create new gpt partition drive with your partitions. I do not suggest a separate /boot in most cases. http://askubuntu.com/questions/336439/any-problems-with-this-partition-scheme Better to use gparted to partition in advance, under device change to gpt first. Then create new partitions. And then during install use Something Else can format and choose mounts.

Comment: Could it be so easy that the order of the systems to load in the EFI could be the problem? I changed the order of them now and then the command line hasn't shown up since. Have only had 2 startups since though. Thanks for the explaining the GPT, didn't know about that before! So the best way to install when I've partitioned the drive is by disconnecting all my other drives before so it's only the one I want Ubuntu on to still be there?

Comment: If not an advanced user, but willing to disconnect hardware that is the safest way. If you use Something Else and partition correctly or partition in advance and choose where to install boot loader to same drive then you do not have to disconnect drive. And how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it will install.

Comment: Turns out that it still boots to command line at first so I'll try reinstalling tomorrow and I'll come back with the results. Mm but I'll disconnect and partition in advance just to be sure this time. Yeah got that, thanks.

Comment: Since Windows is UEFI, be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode, so it installs in UEFI boot mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI AND: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system Not specific to UEFI, but shows Something Else. http://askubuntu.com/questions/312782/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-separate-hard-drive-in-a-dual-boot

Comment: I've now totally reinstalled even just to be sure and disconnected all the other drives. However now in BIOS there are three Ubuntu boot abilities, whereas one is on the old drive. How do I remove that boot option/left files. Is it something left in the MBR or something? (The option that is left is the one who boots directly to the grub when choosing it in the Boot Override option!)

Comment: You have to use efibootmgr as UEFI has its own memory or NVRAM.  http://linux.dell.com/cgi-bin/gitweb/gitweb.cgi?p=efibootmgr.git;a=blob_plain;f=README;hb=HEAD

Comment: Thanks, everything works now. I did however go as far as deleting all ubuntu boot options in efibootmgr and reinstalling Ubuntu again. As I have Ubuntu on a separate drive, so grub didn't detect my Windows partition because I had plugged my drives, however I put them back in and launched ubuntu in recovery mode and reinstalled grub so it found the Windows partition. Now it all works just fine.

Comment: You probably did not have to totally reinstall grub to find Windows, but just run sudo update-grub to refresh grub menu.

Comment: Oh right, didn't know that command existed thanks, good to know in the future.