# I restarted my computer (running Ubuntu desktop 20.04) and it booted to grub mode

Tags: 20.04

How do I reboot to normal mode?
I have no idea how to use grub or why this happened, please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computer boots to Grub command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522363/computer-boots-to-grub-command-line)

Comment: There is Grub, the default bootloader but there isn't any "Grub mode". And, as usual in any modern computer, the first thing to do is to check UEFI settings > Boot and confirm the correct option ("Ubuntu") is still selected and re-enable it if not.

Comment: There is no `grub` mode, but if your system boots to grub rescue - it's usually a sign of a problem. It maybe a user on the system deleted a partition needed to boot the machine in the last session where it worked; or a drive/disk has failed etc.  ie. it's a consequence of a problem on the machine; created by a user in the first place or failing hardware in my second example. You've provided no clues as to potential causes. Was anything changed last working session? (esp. deleted!) have you validated the health of your hardware/drives?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay I just reinstalled Ubuntu